# Funcion MYSQL - IF

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, if

Crear una función que modifique el precioventa de un producto en función de la cantidad en stock:
a) Si la cantidad es <100, la subida del precio será de un valor de 15
b) Si la cantidad está entre 100 y 300, la subida del precio será de un valor de 10
c) Si la cantidad es>300, la subida del precio será de un valor de 5*/

Estoy intentado hacer este ejercicio y no me sale de ninguna manera. Os dejo como el he estado pensado hacer, aunque el codigo que os adjunto da fallos de sintaxis.

```
drop function if exists funcion2; 
set global  log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1 ;

DELIMITER //
create function funcion2(cod_producto int(5))
returns int(5)

begin

declare PrecioVenta int(5);

select PrecioVenta
from productos
where CodigoProducto.productos=cod_producto;

if PrecioVenta<100 then update productos set PrecioVenta=PrecioVenta+15;
elseif (PrecioVenta>100 and PrecioVenta<300) then update productos set PrecioVenta=PrecioVenta+10;
else update productos set PrecioVenta=PrecioVenta+5;

end//

DELIMITER ;
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla productos y un nuevo intento con lo que me habéis recomendado, pero nada...

```
drop function if exists funcion2; 
set global  log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1 ;

DELIMITER //
create function funcion2(cod_producto int(5))
returns int(5)

begin

declare PrecioVenta int(5);

select CantidadEnStock, PrecioVenta
from productos
where productos.CodigoProducto=cod_producto;

UPDATE productos 
    SET PrecioVenta = CASE
                         WHEN CantidadEnStock < 100 THEN PrecioVenta + 15
                         WHEN CantidadEnStock >= 100 AND CantidadEnStock <= 300 THEN PrecioVenta + 10
                         WHEN CantidadEnStock > 300 THEN PrecioVenta + 5
    END
    WHERE productos.CodigoProducto = cod_producto;

return PrecioVenta;

end//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hola oscarp. Decir *pero nada*, o *da fallos de sintaxis* no es útil. Tienes que dar detalles específicos, como los mensajes de error si hay.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código tiene algunos problemas, veamos:

- La función recibe un parámetro que es un código de producto, ese dato lo usas en un `SELECT`, inicialmente para obtener un `PrecioVenta` pero luego no lo estás usando en la sentencia `UPDATE`, por consiguiente terminarías actualizando todos los productos no solamente aquel con el que invocas la función.
- El `SELECT` tiene un problema en el `WHERE`, esto no es válido: `where CodigoProducto.productos=cod_producto`, el uso del alías debiera ser `alias_de_tabla.columna` es decir `where productos.CodigoProducto=cod_producto`
- Las sentencias `IF` como ser `if PrecioVenta<100` no se condice con el enunciado, debiera ser `cantidad`, que tendrías que haber leído anteriormente en el `SELECT`.

Podrías corregir estos temas y mantener más o menos tu idea inicial para la función o puedes simplificar todo en una única sentencia de `UPDATE` que configuras mediante el uso de la sentencia `CASE`:

```
UPDATE productos 
    SET PrecioVenta = CASE
                         WHEN cantidad < 100 THEN PrecioVenta + 15
                         WHEN cantidad >= 100 AND cantidad <= 300 THEN PrecioVenta + 10
                         WHEN cantidad > 300 THEN PrecioVenta + 5
    END
    WHERE CodigoProducto = cod_producto
```

Answer (score 0):

No tengo ni idea de la estructura de tus tablas, asi que aca va una solucion generica.

```
UPDATE productos SET PrecioVenta= PrecioVenta+ 15 where cantidad < 100;
UPDATE productos SET PrecioVenta= PrecioVenta+ 10 where cantidad >= 100 and cantidad < 300;
UPDATE productos SET PrecioVenta= PrecioVenta+ 5 where cantidad >= 300;
```

Si pones esto dentro de tu procedimiento actualizara los valores como los necesitas